# Allocation and fragmentation on the heap

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, heap-memory

I have a complex structure I need to allocate on the heap. It's made of some basic types and custom objects. Those custom objects are made out of some basic types and some other custom objects. Those custom objects are made out of some basic types and some other custom objects, et cetara, et cetera...

The way I've been doing it is storing the basic types as automatic variables while making the custom objects (smart) pointers.

But, since the main object is created as a (smart) pointer, all of this is allocated on the heap anyway, no? But every time I use another (smart) pointer, it does another allocation and fragments the memory, right?

So I shouldn't really be using pointers, save for that initial one to put it on a heap, no? All of the objects that have changeable sizes have the changeable parts stored in a map or a vector, which do allocate stuff on their own, but at this point, this is a necessity anyway since I don't know how many, if any, there will be.

Anyway, am I right to think this way?
The less the pointers are used, the better?

Comment: Please show some code, not to say MCVE.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't optimize prematurely. If you think this is likely an issue, construct an experiment that establishes whether or not it's a problem.

Comment: If it does turn out that fragmentation is a problem, you can always deal with it at that time by using slab allocators or similar.  But most likely it won't turn out to be a problem, so by not worrying about it for now you're likely to save yourself from doing a lot of unnecessary work and adding a significant amount of unnecessary complexity to your program.

Comment: Allocating memory doesn't fragment the heap. Freeing memory sometimes does, but if you free a bunch of things that were allocated at the same time the released memory willl almost certainly be merged, so there will be very little fragmentation.

Comment: Are you using C++ stl containers for your objects?

Comment: It's a large structure so I'm trying to get as much stuff as proper as possible so I don't have to change it later (which this might be). Yes, I'm using stl vectors and maps.The question in general was is there a point in using pointers here or not. I was using them and then realised it might be better not to so I wanted to check. The use case is what it is. A large structure that needs to be accessed and changed. I can do it using both, but there usually is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Use whatever makes more sense from a design point of view.

If it turns out to be to slow (it probably won't, anyway), profile and optimize the bottlenecks.

Comment: I have a large structure that I need to be able to read from and change. he biggest point is that the structure will tend to be modified, Parts of it will (stl containers) will get members added and removed. Given all that, is there any point using pointers to objects in a structure that is already on the heap, or have them just be allocated as part of the object that contains them?